# Return column sorted by 2 other columns with a condition

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a DB which is simply a table with 3 columns:
**viewer_id, movie_id, Ranking** 
(INTEGER) (INTEGER) (TEXT)

Where a row in this table represents that a certain viewer has watched a certain movie.

> If the viewer hasn't ranked the movie yet- the Ranking value is NULL.
>
> If the viewer did rank the movie than the Ranking value is
>   LIKE\DISLIKE

I need to write a query that returns the top 10 viewers id with the highest views and rating count ordered by views count
and then rating count (both in descending order).

So far, I wrote a query that returns a table with viewer_id, movie_watch_count
with the correct information.

```
   SELECT viewer_id , count(*) AS movies_watched 
   FROM viewers_movies_rankings  
   Group By viewer_id
```

I tried adding another column to this table - "ranking_count" which will count for each viewer_id the number of rows where the Ranking value != null.
(So that I will get also the number of movies the viewer ranked,
So the only thing after this to do is to sort by those columns )

but everything I wrote didn't work.
For example **(not working)**

```
SELECT viewer_id , count(*) AS movies_watched,
COUNT(*) AS movies_watched 
HAVING ranking != null 
FROM viewers_movies_rankings  
Group By viewer_id
```

Can you help me?

Comment: Edit your question and provide sample data and desired results.

Answer (score 1):

You would seem to want:

```
SELECT viewer_id , count(*) AS movies_watched,
       COUNT(ranking) as movies_ranked
FROM viewers_movies_rankings  
GROUP BY viewer_id ;
```

`COUNT(<expression>)` counts the number of times the expression is not `NULL` -- and that is exactly what you want to do.

Answer (score 1):

Is this what you want?

```
SELECT
    viewer_id,
    COUNT(*) AS movies_watched,
    COUNT(ranking) AS ranking_count
FROM viewers_movies_rankings
GROUP BY viewer_id
```

The default behavior of the `COUNT` function is that it only counts non `NULL` values.